# What gauge wire for irrigation pump?

Tags: wiring

I have dug an irrigation well (40 feet), and installed this pump: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B005X53JC8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005X53JC8)

It has the following description:  *Red Lion RJS-75-PREM Shallow Well Jet Pump, Cast Iron, 1-HP 24-GPM*

The pump did *not* come with a power cord, and therefore I'll need to wire up a cord and plug to the pressure switch.

What gauge wire does this pump take?

I current have wired up a computer cable, I'm guessing the individual strands in there are maybe 16 or 18 gauge (no idea, really).  I noticed that the chord gets pretty warm when the pump is running.

Should I go with a lower/thicker gauge?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would help to know where you are.  The pump appears to prefer 220v, and another commenter mentioned that it requires at least a 15 amp circuit, which implies at least 14 gauge and possibly lower, depending on distance, .

Comment: I'm in NC.  And I have it switched onto 110v, and the circuit breaker in the breaker box is 30 amp (sorry if my terminology is off, I'm new to this).

Comment: You have a 1hp pump wired to a computer power cord??? Are you aware that that is nearly 18 amps @ 120V??

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Judging by the count of question marks you used, I'm going to assume that this isn't the ideal configuration.  With that being said, what gauge wire should I go with?

Comment: To be honest, judging from your question and comments I am apprehensive giving advice on this. How long will it run? Where do you plan on plugging it in? Will you run a dedicated circuit?

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Sorry for the lack of details. The plug cord will be no more than 24 inches. The pump will run up to 3-4 hours.  It is plugged in in an enclose I build in my backyard around the pump, bladder, well, outlet.  The circuit is dedicated, yes.  Thanks!

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I'd rather be safe than sorry. If I can wire up existing 8 gauge wire I already have (might be a bit too thick?  Perhaps I'll trim a few strands to fit it in the plug?), I'll do that.  If not I'll go not thinner than 12 gauge.  Sound prudent?

Comment: The I would recommend 30a circuit using #10cu and hard wired. IMO your best and most efficient bet would be to run it at 240v and then plug it in. This way you can use easier #12 wire and the plug/receptacle will serve as your required means of disconnect.

Comment: I would NOT do that with the #8. Its such a short run getting the correct wire is not a big deal.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Ok perfect, I'll take your advice.  So just to clarify, that's "10 gauge copper" wire right?

Comment: To run it at 120v yes. Don't forget everything on the circuit would need to be rated 30a, the breaker can be 25 or 30a.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- make that an answer and I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run it at 120v you'll need to have a 25 or 30A breaker and #10cu wire. Typical would be 10/2 cable.

Don't forget everything on the circuit would need to be rated 30a, the breaker can be 25 or 30a.